# Compute N(A) and R(A), when $\epsilon = 0$ and $\epsilon \neq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am quite lost with this since I cannot get any reasonable answer. I tried to compute the nullspace like this: $x \in N(A)$, where $A = \begin{bmatrix}1+ϵ^2 & 1\\1 & 1+ϵ^2\end{bmatrix}$

Then $Ax = 0$

$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1+ϵ^2 & 1  & 0 \\
1 & 1+ϵ^2 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]$

I end up with equations:

$(1+ϵ^2)x_1 + x_2=0$

$x_1 + (1+ϵ^2)x_2 = 0$

When $ϵ = 0$, $x_1$ is just the opposite number of $x_2$, but when $ϵ\neq0$ there is no clear way to express the answer? With the R(A) the answer I get is even more complex..

Comment: The two equations you obtain at the end are lines of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Can you compute their intersection ? Then you can use the rank-nullity theorem to deduce the range.

Comment: Before spending too much time on those equations, first check if $A$ has a nontrivial null space by computing the determinant.

Comment: @Eric Thank you, N(A) is non-trivial when ϵ=0. But it seems to be impossible to say how N(A) looks when ϵ is not equal to zero?

Comment: When $e \neq 0$ the determinant is also nonzero which means you matrix is invertible. Are there any nonzero vectors in the null space of an invertible matrix?

Comment: @Eric Oh yea I get it, do you have any tips of describing the R(A)?

Comment: The range of a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is the set of vectors $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Av=b$ has a solution for some $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Knowing that $A$ is invertible, can you say if there are any $b$ for which $Av=b$ does not have a solution? Also you can use the rank nullity theorem as suggested by someone else. When $\epsilon=0$, just try computing $Av$ where $v=(v_1\  v_2)^T$.

Comment: @Eric Thank you I got it!